# SQL: Create multiple dependent tables in one script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create 2 tables in one script. The first is an image table with a primary key and the second is an article table with a foreign key linked to the image table id. Code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Image')
        CREATE TABLE [Image]
        (
            [ImageId]                       INT IDENTITY(1,1)       NOT NULL,
            [FileName]                      NVARCHAR(20)            NOT NULL,
            [ImageData]                     VARBINARY(MAX)          NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT PK_ImageId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ImageId ASC)
            ON [PRIMARY]
        )

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Article')
        CREATE TABLE Article
        (
            ArticleId                       INT IDENTITY(1,1)       NOT NULL,
            CreatedAt                       DATE                    NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT D_ArticleDate DEFAULT GETDATE(),
            Title                           NVARCHAR(20)            NOT NULL,
            Body                            NVARCHAR(MAX)           NOT NULL,
            MainImageId                     INT                     NULL,
            CONSTRAINT PK_ArticleId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ArticleId ASC)
            ON [PRIMARY],
            CONSTRAINT FK_MainImageId FOREIGN KEY (MainImageId) REFERENCES [Image] (PK_ImageId)
        )
```

If I run the Image query it runs fine. If I then run the Article query it runs fine. If I run both queries in one go, I get the following error:

Foreign key 'FK_MainImageId' references invalid column 'PK_ImageId' in referenced table 'Image'.

Is there a way to do this in one script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be referencing `ImageId` and not the constraint name `PK_ImageId` like this -

`CONSTRAINT FK_MainImageId FOREIGN KEY (MainImageId) REFERENCES [Image] (ImageId)`

and try [**GO**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) between the two batch statements..to execute them at once.

Comment: That's the problem. I was referencing the wrong thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "GO" after the first query. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

In one script, just put a GO in between the two operations.  This divides the script into two batches.  GO is a batch separator supported by SSMS and some other tools, like SQLCMD.